# Implementation of *nix ipcalc

Tags: python, parsing, console, networking, formatting

I posted a JS subnetting calc before, but I wanted to try a CLI version, so I made this.

The parts I'm most worried about are:

1. structure (could I refactor the layout better?)
2. Did I goof any math?

This was primarily a challenge so I could get better at writing Python... obviously it'll never compete with Perl or C.

Also, I do know I need to comment more/better.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
some comments

"""

import argparse
import math
import socket
import struct

prog = 'ipcalc'
usage = '{0} [-n NUMHOST | -s SUBMASK] [IPv4 address/mask]'.format(prog)
description = ('Subnetting Calculator\n=====================\nTakes both an '
               'IPv4 address and either a submask in CIDR notation,\n'
               'quad-dotted notation, or an arbitary number of hosts.'
               '\n\nAddress range, host values, submasks, etc.')
epilogue = (
    'example:\n\tipcalc 192.168.0.1/24\n\tipcalc 192.168.0.1 24\n\t'
    'ipcalc -n 192.168.0.1 250')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage=usage,
                                 description=description,
                                 epilog=epilogue,
                                 formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)

parser.add_argument(
    'ip',
    metavar='IPv4 address/mask',
    type=str,
    help='CIDR notation of IPv4 address\n192.168.0.1/24')
parser.add_argument(
    'prefix',
    metavar='CIDR prefix',
    type=str,
    help='CIDR prefix OR submask\n24, 16, etc. OR 255.255.0.0, etc.',
    const=None,
    nargs='?')
parser.add_argument(
    '-n',
    '--numhost',
    type=int,
    help='integer number of hosts')
parser.add_argument(
    '-c',
    '--colors',
    action='store_true',
    help='Colors off')
parser.add_argument('--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s 1.0')

args = parser.parse_args()

HEADER = '\033[95m'
OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
WARNING = '\033[93m'
FAIL = '\033[91m'
ENDC = '\033[0m'

if False is not args.colors:
    HEADER = OKGREEN = OKBLUE = WARNING = FAIL = ENDC = '\033[0m'

MAX_BIT_INT = 32
MAX_BIT_HEX = 0xFF
MAX_BIT_BIN = 255
THIRTY_TWO_BITS = 4294967295

big_int = struct.Struct('!I')


def set_base(prefix, hosts):
    """
    Returns the 'base' which is an int which is <= 32 and >= 0
    Represents number of 'set' bits.

    See: https://www.google.com/search?q=hamming+weight

    """
    if None is not hosts:
        base = int(set_bits_from_host(hosts))
        return base
    elif None is not prefix:
        try:
            base = int(prefix)
        except ValueError:
            base = set_bits_from_submask(prefix)
        return base


def set_bits_from_host(num_hosts):
    """
    Returns base from number of desired hosts
    See set_base()

    """
    if 0 is not num_hosts:
        num_hosts = MAX_BIT_INT - int(math.ceil(math.log(num_hosts, 2)))
    return num_hosts


def set_bits_from_submask(submask):
    """
    Returns base from subnetwork mask
    See set_base()

    """
    # [23:47] <runciter>: struct.unpack('!I', socket.inet_aton(ip))
    # from user 'runciter' in #python on freenode IRC
    try:
        uint32_t = big_int.unpack(socket.inet_aton(submask))[0]
    except socket.error:
        quit('{0}Invalid subnet mask entered.'.format(FAIL))

    # http://books.google.com/books?id=iBNKMspIlqEC&pg=PA66#v=onepage&q&f=false
    uint32_t = uint32_t - ((uint32_t >> 1) & 0x55555555)
    uint32_t = (uint32_t & 0x33333333) + ((uint32_t >> 2) & 0x33333333)
    uint32_t = (uint32_t + (uint32_t >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F
    uint32_t = uint32_t + (uint32_t >> 8)
    uint32_t = uint32_t + (uint32_t >> 16)
    return uint32_t & 0x0000003F


def submask_from_set_bits(base):
    """
    Returns a subnetwork mask from the base

    """
    try:
        mask = ~0 << (32 - base)
    except ValueError:
        quit(
            '{0}CIDR prefix too large.\n{1}Must be <= 32, >= 0.'.format(
                FAIL,
                WARNING))
    return '{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}'.format(
        mask >> 24 & MAX_BIT_BIN,
        mask >> 16 & MAX_BIT_BIN,
        mask >> 8 & MAX_BIT_BIN,
        mask & MAX_BIT_BIN)


def wildcard(base):
    """
    Returns Cisco wildcard address.
    Same as inverse of subnetwork mask

    """
    mask = ~(~0 << (32 - base))
    return '{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}'.format(
        mask >> 24 & MAX_BIT_BIN,
        mask >> 16 & MAX_BIT_BIN,
        mask >> 8 & MAX_BIT_BIN,
        mask & MAX_BIT_BIN)


def max_hosts(base):
    """
    Calculates max number of hosts network can support

    """
    base = base or 0
    if base >= 2:
        base = 2 ** (MAX_BIT_INT - base)
    return base - 2


def broadcast_addr(sm, ip):
    """
    Returns broadcast address of network

    """
    bn = ip | (~sm & THIRTY_TWO_BITS)
    # To Do: Get this gross thing to work with struct and socket
    return ".".join(map(lambda n: str(bn >> n & MAX_BIT_HEX), [24, 16, 8, 0]))


def network_addr(sm, ip):
    """
    Returns network address of network

    """
    bn = ip & sm
    return socket.inet_ntoa(big_int.pack(bn))


def subnets(base):
    """
    Returns maximum number of available subnets

    """
    mod_base = base % 8
    return 2 ** mod_base if mod_base else 2 ** 8


def display_bits():
    """
    Prints visualization of on/off bits

    """
    """
    try:
        b_int = bin(integer)[2:]
        return '.'.join(b_int[i:i+8] for i in xrange(0, len(b_int), 8))
    except TypeError:
        return big_int.unpack(socket.inet_aton(integer))

    """
    pass


def ip_class(ip):
    """
    Returns class of IPv4 address

    """

    if 0xC0000000 == ip & 0xC0000000:
        return 'Class C'
    elif 0x80000000 == ip & 0x80000000:
        return 'Class B'
    elif 0 == ip & 0x80000000:
        return 'Class A'
    else:
        return False

# Set initial values

ip_input = args.ip.split('/')[0]
hosts_input = args.numhost

try:
    prefix_input = args.ip.split('/')[1]
except IndexError:
    prefix_input = args.prefix

# Set base for calculations
base = set_base(prefix_input, hosts_input)

try:
    IP_32_BIT = big_int.unpack(socket.inet_aton(ip_input))[0]
except socket.error:
    quit('{0}Invalid IPv4 address entered.'.format(FAIL))

SM_32_BIT = big_int.unpack(socket.inet_aton(submask_from_set_bits(base)))[0]

# Set values we'll be modifying
submask = submask_from_set_bits(base)
network_address = network_addr(SM_32_BIT, IP_32_BIT)
broadcast_address = broadcast_addr(SM_32_BIT, IP_32_BIT)

network_min = network_addr(SM_32_BIT + 1, IP_32_BIT)
network_max = '{0}{1}'.format(
    broadcast_address[:-1], int(broadcast_address[-1]) - 1)

print 'Address:   {0}{1}{2}'.format(HEADER, ip_input, ENDC)
print 'Netmask:   {0}{1} = {2}{3}'.format(HEADER, submask_from_set_bits(base), base, ENDC)
print 'Wildcard:  {0}{1}{2}'.format(HEADER, wildcard(base), ENDC)
print 'Class:     {0}{1}{2}'.format(HEADER, ip_class(IP_32_BIT), ENDC)
print '{0}-->{1}'.format(OKGREEN, ENDC)
print 'Network:   {0}{1}/{2}{3}'.format(OKBLUE, network_address, base, ENDC)
print 'HostMin:   {0}{1}{2}'.format(OKBLUE, network_min, ENDC)
print 'HostMax:   {0}{1}{2}'.format(OKBLUE, network_max, ENDC)
print 'Broadcast: {0}{1}{2}'.format(OKBLUE, broadcast_address, ENDC)
print 'Subnets:   {0}{1}{2}'.format(OKBLUE, subnets(base), ENDC)
print 'Hosts/Net: {0}{1}{2}'.format(OKBLUE, max_hosts(base), ENDC)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice tool! And I think it's pretty well done. There's still some room for improvements though ;-)

#### Structure

Much of your code is within functions, which is good. But then, roughly half of the code is in the global namespace. It would be better have pretty much everything inside functions. For example:

> ```
> prog = 'ipcalc'
> usage = '{0} [-n NUMHOST | -s SUBMASK] [IPv4 address/mask]'.format(prog)
> description = ('Subnetting Calculator\n=====================\nTakes both an '
>                'IPv4 address and either a submask in CIDR notation,\n'
>                'quad-dotted notation, or an arbitary number of hosts.'
>                '\n\nAddress range, host values, submasks, etc.')
> ```

All this and similar stuff would be good inside a function that's in charge of parsing arguments, for example:

```
def parse_args():
    # ...


def main():
    # ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_args()
    main(args)
```

#### Unit testing

Since many of the functions can be tricky to get right, it would be good to unit test them, for example `set_bits_from_submask`, `submask_from_set_bits`, and many of the others too.

*Note that moving all functionality inside functions as I mentioned in the earlier point is a requirement before you can add unit tests. You cannot import the script for testing purposes if it immediately launches the command line interface. Once all the code is properly inside functions, this won't be a problem anymore, and unit testing becomes possible.*

#### Pythonic expressions

These are strange and non-Pythonic examples:

> ```
> if False is not args.colors:
>     HEADER = OKGREEN = OKBLUE = WARNING = FAIL = ENDC = '\033[0m'
>
> if None is not hosts:
>     # ...
> ```

The Pythonic way would be:

```
if args.colors:
    HEADER = OKGREEN = OKBLUE = WARNING = FAIL = ENDC = '\033[0m'

if hosts:
    # ...
```

Also this:

> ```
> uint32_t = uint32_t - ((uint32_t >> 1) & 0x55555555)
> uint32_t = uint32_t + (uint32_t >> 8)
> ```

More common and simpler to write like this:

```
uint32_t -= ((uint32_t >> 1) & 0x55555555)
uint32_t += (uint32_t >> 8)
```

There are other similar examples in the code, I suggest to update everywhere similarly.

#### Misc

I find it not intuitive that a flag called `-c` or `--colors` actually turns colors *off*. (Hard to suggest something better though... `--no-colors`, `--simple`, `--plain` ?)

Instead of this:

> ```
> epilogue = (
>     'example:\n\tipcalc 192.168.0.1/24\n\tipcalc 192.168.0.1 24\n\t'
>     'ipcalc -n 192.168.0.1 250')
> ```

I would find more readable this way:

```
epilogue = (
    'example:\n'
    '\tipcalc 192.168.0.1/24\n'
    '\tipcalc 192.168.0.1 24\n'
    '\tipcalc -n 192.168.0.1 250')
```

Comment: I appreciate your review. How does this look? https://github.com/EricLagerg/ipcalc/blob/master/ipcalc.py
I'd respond further but I need to run off to work. Thanks again! - Eric